# ngUpgrade unit testing with karma, systemjs and angular test-shim

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular, systemjs, typescript1.6

I'm preparing a large project to migrate from ng1 to ng2. Followed the instructions here => https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

My sanity unit test (no imports, just basic math operations) succeeds (but are executed twice). As soon as I add more files in the karma.conf.js (my app files, managed by systemjs) I get followed error from karma / jasmine for each file:

```
 TypeError: Unexpected anonymous System.register call.
```

karam.conf.js

```js
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Sat Jan 02 2016 15:05:49 GMT+0100 (CET)

module.exports = function(config) {

  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'phantomjs-shim'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [

  // ng1 resources
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',

  // ng2 resources
  'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
  'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
  'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
  'node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js',
  'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
  'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
  'node_modules/angular2/bundles/upgrade.dev.js',
  'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
  'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js',
  'node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.dev.js',

  // load test shim for systemjs support
  'tests/shims/karma-test-shim.js',

  // app and test resources
  {pattern: 'app/core/*.js', include: false, watched: true}, // <= systemjs anonymous register call issue!
  {pattern: 'tests/unit/**/*.spec.js', include: false, watched: true}
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],

 // proxied base paths
 proxies: {
 },


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
  '**/*.js' : ['coverage']
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

 // config coverage output
    coverageReporter: {
   type : 'html',
   dir : 'tests/unit/coverage/'
    },


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


 // plugins
 plugins: [
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-coverage',
  'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-phantomjs-shim'
 ],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity

  });

}
```

core.controller.tree.ts

```js
/**
 * CORE CONTROLLER TREE
 *
 * @desc  tree controller of core module
 * @date 2015-10-30
 * @version 2
 */



'use strict';



// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //



interface ITreeController {

 tree    :    any[];
 types :    any[];
 q  :    string;

}



// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //



export class TreeController implements ITreeController {

 // properties
 public types : any[];
 public q  : string;



 /**
  * constructor
  *
  * @desc constructor
  * @param  $stateParams - any  - state params
  * @param  tree   - any  - tree items
  * @return {Tree}
  * @ngInject
  */
 constructor(private $stateParams : any, public tree : any) {

  // assign DI values
  this.q   = $stateParams.q;
  this.types = $stateParams.types;

 }

}
```

core.controller.tree.js (ts compiled)

```js
/**
 * CORE CONTROLLER TREE
 *
 * @desc  tree controller of core module
 * @date 2015-10-30
 * @version 2
 */
'use strict';
System.register([], function(exports_1) {
    var TreeController;
    return {
        setters:[],
        execute: function() {
            // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
            // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
            TreeController = (function () {
                /**
                 * constructor
                 *
                 * @desc constructor
                 * @param  $stateParams - any  - state params
                 * @param  tree   - any  - tree items
                 * @return {Tree}
                 * @ngInject
                 */
                function TreeController($stateParams, tree) {
                    this.$stateParams = $stateParams;
                    this.tree = tree;
                    // assign DI values
                    this.q = $stateParams.q;
                    this.types = $stateParams.types;
                }
                return TreeController;
            })();
            exports_1("TreeController", TreeController);
        }
    }
});
//# sourceMappingURL=core.controller.tree.js.map
```

tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata" : true,
    "removeComments": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "bower_components",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

tests/shims/karma-test-shim.js

```js
/**
 * ANGULAR2 TEST SHIM
 *
 * @desc  test shim for angular2 using systemjs as module loader
 * @date 2016-01-02
 * @version 1.0.0
 */



'use strict';




// Cancel Karma's synchronous start,
// we will call `__karma__.start()` later, once all the specs are loaded.
__karma__.loaded = function() {};
System.config({
 packages: {
  'base/app': {
   defaultExtension: false,
   format: 'register',
   map: Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).
   filter(onlyAppFiles).
   reduce(function createPathRecords(pathsMapping, appPath) {
    // creates local module name mapping to global path with karma's fingerprint in path, e.g.:
    // './hero.service': '/base/src/app/hero.service.js?f4523daf879cfb7310ef6242682ccf10b2041b3e'
    var moduleName = appPath.replace(/^\/base\/app\//, './').replace(/\.js$/, '');
    pathsMapping[moduleName] = appPath + '?' + window.__karma__.files[appPath];
    console.log(pathsMapping);
    return pathsMapping;
   }, {})
  }
 }
});
System.import('angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter').then(function(browser_adapter) {
 browser_adapter.BrowserDomAdapter.makeCurrent();
}).then(function() {
 return Promise.all(
  Object.keys(window.__karma__.files) // All files served by Karma.
   .filter(onlySpecFiles)
   .map(function(moduleName) {
    // loads all spec files via their global module names
    console.info('spec loaded: ' + moduleName);
    return System.import(moduleName);
   }));
}).then(function() {
 __karma__.start();
}, function(error) {
 __karma__.error(error.stack || error);
});
function onlyAppFiles(filePath) {
 return /^\/base\/app\/.*\.js$/.test(filePath)
}
function onlySpecFiles(path) {
 return /\.spec\.js$/.test(path);
}
```

my file structure

```
root
 |- app
 |   |- core
 |   |- ...
 |- tests
 |    |- unit
 |    |- e2e
 |    |- shims
 |- node_modules
 |- bower_components
 |- index.html
```

the app it self works when I call it over the browser. but not when I try to run tests against it. thank you very much for any hints!

Comment: How are you importing, for example `TreeController` in your test files? What's your `core.controller.tree.spec.ts` like (just imports, test logic is not important atm)? Looks to me issue might be there...

Comment: thanks for your reply! at the moment I don't have any spec files for the app itself. I just wanted to add unit tests to this projects which I have to maintain now. the imports of the spec and app files are handled over systemjs with the "tests/shims/karma-test-shim.js" script (added in my post) provided by angular. the error occurs right after adding a .spec.js file in my app folder. I just moved my "sanity"-Test spec into the app folder (without any further dependencies / imports). I thought, that it could be something with a wrong systemjs transpilation of my app files? thx a lot!

Comment: I had similar issue and been struggling with it for few days, until I dissected karma.conf.js and karma.shim.js and basically rewrote them line by line checking for errors every step of the way (: Try to comment out some imported files, and check what files are actually processed. You can add `.filter(function (path) { console.log(path); return true; })` before and after filters in karma.shim.js, for example. Take a look at [my version](https://gist.github.com/sasxa/0939f5bb00285e82af21), I renamed some stuff to better understand what it is. Hope it helps...

Comment: if you post your gist as answer, I flag it :) omg! thx soooo much!!! I don't know what it was at the end, but my unit tests are working. thx a lot!